# Can't run react app or even create because of npm ERR! syscall spawn powershell-Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu

Am usung ubuntu 20.04 and I don't know why am getting this error

> venuspot@0.0.0 dev
> vite

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn powershell
npm ERR! path /home/timothy/Development/project/Venu-Spot-FrontEnd
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent spawn powershell ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/timothy/.npm/_logs/2023-01-10T13_40_13_506Z-debug-0.log

I've tried almost all online suggestions maybe someone has an idea

Comment: can you please post package.json file

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Am not able to even create a react app.

Comment: ok soo can you try to update npm

Comment: I updated it and still got the error message.

Answer (score -1):

try to run this command :
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
after this check version of npm :
npm -v

Comment: am using ubuntu

Comment: can you check the permission on the folder Venu-Spot-FrontEnd ?

Comment: Is there a way I can uninstall npm, node, nvm then install them again, because the project was working this morning and I don't know why 'npm ERR! syscall spawn powershell' keeps popping up and am using ubuntu.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove